# vb.net set properties of columns of gridview dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, .net, vb.net

Hello StackOverFlow Family

I have a table in my database that contains all columns of all grid views that already have been created on vb.net application form as below.

**Using this table, I want to control on each gridview in my application instead of adding columns' properties in vb.net manually which mean each time I want to modify any property, I have to do it on application level and create new exe file.**

[image: table]

my program retrieves data from above table (from database)

I need to modify columns properties dynamically based on data stored in this table

Thanks in advance

Comment: Columns of the gridview, or columns of the table.  What have you tried so far and how does the result differ from your expectations?

Comment: @Hursey , my datagridview data (datagridview name, column name, property need to modify, expected property value type, property value) is stored in table in database.

I need to modify columns' properties dynamically, by inserting, updating or deleting data in database table

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some examples.
If you want to change the properties on a full column you can do like this:

```
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Yellow
```

If you want to change the properties of a cell that has the value "TextToSearch" you can do it like this:

```
Dim x,y As Integer
For y = 0 to DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 
For x = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    If DataGridView1.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value.ToString = "TextToSearch" Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(y).Cells(x).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        DataGridView1.Rows(y).Cells(x).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
    End If
Next
Next
```

Comment: thanks alot for your reply
my datagridview data (datagridview name, column name, property need to modify, expected property value type, property value) is stored in table in database. I need to modify columns' properties dynamically, by inserting, updating or deleting data in database table @Miguel